# Angular2 - OnInit : Values returned from Service' subscribe function does not get assigned to Component field/s

Tags: angular

I'm trying out Angular2 and have been following their tutorials.

I currently have a Service that gets data from a json server:

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { User } from './user';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  private usersUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/users';

  getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.usersUrl) //the request won't go out until something subscribes to the observable
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError); // pass an error message back to the component for presentation to the user but only if we can say something the user can understand and act upon
  }

  private extractData(response: Response) {
    if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) {
       throw new Error('Bad response status: ' + response.status);
    }
    let body = response.json(); // parse JSON string into JavaScript objects

    return body.data || { };
  }

  private handleError (error: any) {
    // In a real world app, we might send the error to remote logging infrastructure before returning/sending the error
   let errMsg = error.message || 'Server error'; // transform the error into a user-friendly message

   return Observable.throw(errMsg); // returns the message in a new, failed observable
  }

}
```

And my Component:

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { User } from '../common/user/user';
import { UserService } from '../common/user/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: '/app/nav/nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['/app/nav/nav.component.css']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
  errorMsg: string;
  users: User[];

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  getUsers() {
    this.userService
    .getUsers()
    .subscribe(
      function(users) {
        console.log('users ' + users);
        this.users = users;
        console.log('this.users ' + this.users);
      }, function(error) {
        console.log('error ' + error);
      });
    // users => this.users = users,
    // error => this.errorMsg = <any>error);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
    console.log('ngOnit after getUsers() ' + this.users);
  }
}
```

My problem is, the data returned from the subscribed function is not being passed/assigned to my Component property 'users' after the getUsers() invocation completes. I do know that the data is returned to the component from the service method call because I'm able to log the data within the userService().getUsers method. The weird thing is, the console.log invocation on my ngOnInit is being printed on my dev console first before the console.logs within my getUsers method, although I invoke the getUsers first:

```ts
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
    console.log('ngOnit after getUsers() ' + this.users);
  }
```

Dev console screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because `this.getUsers()` and then `this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(...)` only schedules a call to make a request to the server. Eventually when the response from the server arrives (`console.log('ngOnit after getUsers() ' + this.users);` was already executed before the call to the server was even made) then the function you passed to `subscribe()` is executed.

This should do what you want:

```ts
  getUsers() {
    return this.userService
    .getUsers()
    .map(
      (users) => {
        console.log('users ' + users);
        this.users = users;
        console.log('this.users ' + this.users);
      })
     .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error ' + error);
        throw error;
      });
    // users => this.users = users,
    // error => this.errorMsg = <any>error);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers().subscribe(_ => {;
      console.log('ngOnit after getUsers() ' + this.users);
    });
  }
```

In `getUsers()` I use `map()` instead of subscribe, so we can subscribe later in order to be able to get code executed when the response arrived.

Then in `ngOnInit()` we use the `subscribe()` (`subscribe()` is necessary, otherwise would `http.get()` would never be executed) and pass the code we want to be executed when the response arrives.

I also changed `function ()` to `() =>`. This way `this` works inside the following code block `() => { ... }`, otherwise it wouldn't.

Don't forget to add

```ts
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
```

otherwise these operators won't be recoginzed.

Comment: Thanks for your response sir, after trying this out, the value does get printed within the ngOnInit console log invocation, but I still get an undefined value when I reference the users property in my template. Using the async feature as an alternative to implicitly subscribe to the Observable returned from the service get method call works though. I still don't get why the above wouldn't work when it does work on Angular's tutorial?

Comment: The error is caused by Angular trying to bind the value before `ngOnInit()`. Just use `{{users?.xxx}}` instead of `{{users.xxx}}` to not get the error.

Comment: That fixed my issue sir. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear :) It's called the safe-navigation or Elvis operator in case you want to look it up. I was on the phone when I wrote the previous comment therefore I kept it short.

Comment: If i have a parent component subscribing to getUser() data, will I need to subscribe in the child component as well to access the same user data?

Comment: Sorry, but that's not enough information. I'd suggest you create a new question where you provide some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish. It depends on how you pass the data. If you assign the result to a property and bind to that property there is nothing to be taken care of (except that you don't access properties of the value while it's not there). There are too many possible ways you pass the data along for me to know what to assume.

Comment: Hi @GünterZöchbauer if you get time can you answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51673368/observable-subscription-does-not-work-when-written-in-ngonit-in-ie

thanks and regards!

Answer (score 0):

for me this is works like magic
i was need to get data from api to initialize datatable component

1- on your http service create normal get request like this :

```
  public get(url: string):Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>( url );
   }
```

2- on your component :

```
constructor(private HttpSvc: HttpService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.render();
  }    
render() {
        let options = this.options || {};
          this.HttpSvc.Get('your api url').subscribe(data => {
            this.Tableset = data;
            options = {
              data: this.Tableset.data,
              columns: this.Tableset.columns,
              dom: 'Bfrtip',
              buttons: this.Tableset.buttons,
              autoWidth: false,
              pageLength: 2,
              retrieve: true,
              responsive: true
            };
          }, err => {console.log(err); },
          () => {
            this.renderDetails(options); //<-- can call any other method after call end
          });
    }
```

here the full example [link](https://medium.com/ramsatt/integrate-data-table-with-angular-8-application-with-json-backend-f1071feeb18f)