# Angular 2 Google Maps plot Polyline by fetching lat lng from Web API

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api2

I am using Angular 2 Google Maps. I have issues plotting PolyLine on google maps by getting Lat Lng data from SQL Server in JSON format using WEB API. Data received from POSTMAN is correct & as below:

```
[{"Lat":18.587100,"Lng":73.790179},{"Lat":18.587629,"Lng":73.787883},{"Lat":18.588219,"Lng":73.784922},{"Lat":18.588542,"Lng":73.781277},{"Lat":18.588617,"Lng":73.779075},{"Lat":18.588922,"Lng":73.777101},{"Lat":18.589430,"Lng":73.777637},{"Lat":18.590361,"Lng":73.779418}]
```

**I am getting response in this.coordinates but after complete execution of ngOnInit(). I also tried setTimeout() but of no help**. I get the map displayed but without PolyLine. Below is the code:

> maps.component.html

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

> maps.component.ts

```
public coordinates: ICoordinates[] = [];
private errorMessage: any = '';

  constructor( private _getMapDataService : GetMapDataService) { 
    this.getCoordinates().subscribe(_ => {;
      setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Coordinates in ngOnInit -> ' + this.coordinates)
      }
    ,10000)      
    })
   }

  getCoordinates(){
    return this._getMapDataService.getCoordinatesData()
    .map(
      (coordinates) => {            
        console.log('Coordinates in method (1) -> ' + coordinates);
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
        console.log('Coordinates in Method (2) -> ' + this.coordinates);        
      },
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      const myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(this._getMapDataService.getLatData(), this._getMapDataService.getLngData());
      const mapOptions = {
          zoom: 15,
          center: myLatlng,
          scrollwheel: false, // we disable de scroll over the map, it is a really annoing when you scroll through page
          styles: [
              {'featureType': 'water', 'stylers': [{'saturation': 43}, {'lightness': -11}, {'hue': '#0088ff'}]},
              {'featureType': 'road', 'elementType': 'geometry.fill', 'stylers': [{'hue': '#ff0000'},
              {'saturation': -100}, {'lightness': 99}]},
              {'featureType': 'road', 'elementType': 'geometry.stroke', 'stylers': [{'color': '#808080'},
              {'lightness': 54}]},
              {'featureType': 'landscape.man_made', 'elementType': 'geometry.fill', 'stylers': [{'color': '#ece2d9'}]},
              {'featureType': 'poi.park', 'elementType': 'geometry.fill', 'stylers': [{'color': '#ccdca1'}]},
              {'featureType': 'road', 'elementType': 'labels.text.fill', 'stylers': [{'color': '#767676'}]},
              {'featureType': 'road', 'elementType': 'labels.text.stroke', 'stylers': [{'color': '#ffffff'}]},
              {'featureType': 'poi', 'stylers': [{'visibility': 'off'}]},
              {'featureType': 'landscape.natural', 'elementType': 'geometry.fill', 'stylers': [{'visibility': 'on'},
              {'color': '#b8cb93'}]},
              {'featureType': 'poi.park', 'stylers': [{'visibility': 'on'}]},
              {'featureType': 'poi.sports_complex', 'stylers': [{'visibility': 'on'}]},
              {'featureType': 'poi.medical', 'stylers': [{'visibility': 'on'}]},
              {'featureType': 'poi.business', 'stylers': [{'visibility': 'simplified'}]}
          ]
      };
      const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

      var business_locations = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: this.coordinates, // Here this.coordinates is undefined
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 4
      });

      business_locations.setMap(map);
  }
```

> coordinates.cs

```
export interface ICoordinates {
    Lat: number,
    Lng: number
}
```

> GetMapDataService

```
getCoordinatesData(): Observable<ICoordinates[]> {     
return this._http.get(this.url)
           .map(this.extractData)
           .catch(this.handleError);
}

private extractData(res: Response){
    let body = res.json(); // Here response is received after complete execution of ngOnInit()
    return body || [];
  }

  private handleError(error: any){
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
                 error.status ? '${ error.status } - ${ error.statusText }' : 'Server Error';
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
```

I am getting Lat Lng data in **GetMapDataService** but I am not able to get it in **coordinates** variable.

I think this problem is related to async rendering. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37230545/angular2-oninit-values-returned-from-service-subscribe-function-does-not-ge) on Stack Overflow itself which is related to my issue. I am getting value in this.coordinates but the page is rendered before.

Can anyone help me with this. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: How do you check that your data is empty after sucessful response from server?

Comment: In service subscribe, I am getting array of Lat Lng in **value**. But this **value** array is not assigned to **this.coordinates**.

Comment: It is assigned if you've assigned it. The problem is that you're probably trying to use it before callback inside .subscribe is executed. Read about asynchronous nature of JavaScript.

Comment: Yes i am trying to use it in ngOnInit() but the value is received after component is rendered. I have updated the code above. Can you guide me on this.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Can you help me on this???

Comment: Please create a live reproduction.