# observable subscription does not work when written in ngOnit() in IE

Tags: angular5, angular2-observables, behaviorsubject

I have defined a behavior subject:

**component.ts**

```js
bsub1: BehaviorSubject<Array<any>> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
```

And called next() on it:

**html:**

```html
<button (click) = getData()>Data</button>
```

**component.ts:**

```js
getData() {
    getSomething(value, bsub1);
}
```

**service.ts**

```js
getSomething(value, _observable) {
    //do something

    _observable.next(retun)
    somevariable.map(p => {
        return { "a": value1, "b": value2 }
    });
}
```

And made a subscription:

**component.ts**

```js
 ngOnInit() {
     bsub1.subscribe(list=>{
         console.log("subscribed to bsub1")
     });
 }
```

But my code does not reach upto subscription after call to getSomething().
It reaches there when component loads but when next() is called after that it does not subscribe.
this happen only in IE 11 whereas in edge, chrome and firefox it is working.

Can someone explain me this behavior?

Comment: Can you please create a complete example in stackblitz.com? I think your question doesn't contain all information required to diagnose the problem.

Comment: You are @GünterZöchbauer. I spent 2 days to figureout why observable is not subscribing when I write subscription in ngOnit where as when I diagnosed my code within bsub1.subscribe(list=>{
         console.log("subscribed to bsub1")
     });

I came to know that it breaks on IE, fixing that for IE fixed the subscription.
I apologize for not describing my prob properly.

Comment: There was some code inside  bsub1.subscribe(list=>{
         console.log("subscribed to bsub1")

         this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('li.newlist').forEach((ele) => {
         //code here
        })
     });  
is not supported in IE. So I replaced it with with    const newList= Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".newlist"));

        newList.forEach((ele) => {
         //code here
        }); and after this subscription worked.

Comment: I have one major concern regarding where I am writing subscription. I made subscription in ngOninit and ngOninit triggeres when component loads. If you can explain this concept I will grateful. Thanks for your precious time.

Comment: Sorry but it's not clear to what you ask to get explained. The lifecycle callbacks are explained in angular.io.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer If you look at my question I have subscribed to observer in ngOnInit() and I call next on it within service function getSomething() (or when ever required) and I receive data in where I have subscribed. How come code reach to  bsub1.subscribe as it is called in ngOnInit() and ngOnInit is triggered only when component is loaded, it is not like Docheck() which triggers after every few secs.