# Angular 9: Object getting udefined in ngOinit even after assignment

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I am trying to access an object which is assigned by function in ngOnInit, but console log showing it undefined, whereas the same variable is accessible inside LoadSelCompanies subscription block:

```
export class dealComponent implements OnInit {
  selfcompanies;
  self;
  dealForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.AddControls();
    this.LoadSelCompanies();
    console.log(this.selfcompanies);
  }

  LoadSelCompanies() {
    this.userService.LoadCompanyInfo().subscribe(data => {
      this.selfcompanies = data;
      console.log(data);
      console.log(this.selfcompanies);
    });
  }
```

I am clueless about it, please help.

Comment: selfcompanies is executing before service call / assignment finished.

Comment: Method `this.LoadSelCompanies();` doing http call, while it return something response before that `console.log(this.selfcompanies);` runs. See https://www.zeolearn.com/magazine/asynchronous-nature-of-javascript Try to use `async/awit`

Comment: A good way to spot this kind of problem is to put a couple of breakpoints in (the console logs will do the same but it's good to see the results). One on the console.log line in ngOnInit and the other on the console.log(this.selfcompanies) in the LoadSelCompanies and see which break point gets hit first. As with the console.Log the ngOnInnit one will trigger first because the observable has not finished yet.

Comment: @ajrthegreat I am agreed on everybody's part. If I see in the console, I get json object first in  the log and then undefined.

Comment: also tried to change my code something like this as I understand the asynchronous behaviour https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37230545/angular2-oninit-values-returned-from-service-subscribe-function-does-not-ge But this is again not working

Answer (score 1):

It is a classic race condition problem.

LoadCompanyInfo() returns an observable which is asynchronous,
and therefor

```
console.log(this.selfcompanies);
```

occurs before the assignment.

```
this.selfcompanies = data;
```