# ngOnInit and store value in array variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating a function to get data from an API.

But I need to call this function on `ngOnInit` and store value in array variable.

```
MyVaule : any;
MYvalue = MyLocation();
```

But `MyValue` is always `null` inside `MyLocation`

Comment: Please add code snippet or stack Blitz url.

Comment: subscribe to MyLocation in ngOnInit

Comment: can i explain here

Comment: Can you Pls explain more ..

Comment: same issue facing..        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37230545/angular2-oninit-values-returned-from-service-subscribe-function-does-not-ge

Comment: Is it `MyVaule`, `MYvalue` or `MyValue`? At least proof-read your question, since it only contais few words...

Answer (score 1):

You should have a code, similar on this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  value: any;

  constructor(private apiSrv: MyApiService){};

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMyValue();
  }

  getMyValue() {
    this.apiSrv.getData().subscribe(res => this.value = res);
  }
}
```

Comment: i need store value like this ngOnInit() {
 Myvalue =   this.getMyValue();
  }

Comment: also used above code .. nut no luck .. getting      
 value  undefined

Comment: I suggest you to read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps .

After that maybe this: https://angular.io/start